# submitting several forms with their values by json/ajax, gives me a parseerror

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

On my website I've got an jquery accordion plugin. In order to collect all form data (from several forms) I'm using this line:    `$('#form_values').val($('form').serialize())`. Then I submit the data to my php file, which in this case contains:

```
<?php 
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
return json_encode(array("error" => "bad table name"));
?>
```

I would expect that my json/ajax/jquery script would display an alert box with "bad table name", but instead it just displays an alertbox with the text: Parseerror.
My jquery script:

```
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:$('#form_values').val($('form').serialize()),
    url:'handle.php',
    dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert("sucesso: "+data.msg);
                window.location='index.php';
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert (textStatus);}



  });
```

I haven't got a clue what's going wrong here.. hopefully someone is willing to help me out.

Comment: It's your data property that is the problem. Why are you posting the data that way? And you should use `console.log()` rather than `alert()`. `alert()` is no good for troubleshooting.

Comment: use `data: $('form').serialize(),`, this will submit all input fields with name attributes inside all form elements on your page

Comment: Too be honest, it's the first time I'm using json, I wrote this script by following tutorials. The console.log gives me Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when used on the $('#form_values').val($('form').serialize()) line. what would be the correct way to post the data ? An example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @LcLk, it gives me same Parseerror

Comment: Didn't see the JSON part, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `serializeArray` instead of `serialize` and then convert it to a JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
data:JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray()),
url:'handle.php',
dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("sucesso: "+data.msg);
            window.location='index.php';
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert (textStatus);}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that somehow, the server script does not return json (use firebux/other debugging tools to check the response). As you specified that the response's type should be json, you get a parseerror.

Edit: are you sending the form to the right url? e.g. /handle.php instead of handle.php?